# Update table from query results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that gets data from various tables:

```
qry_Values (Rem_ID, Value)
```

and a table:

```
tbl_Rem (Rem_ID, Value, other_value)
```

How do I update the `tbl_Rem.Value` with the `qry_Values.Value` (where the `Rem_ID`s match) using SQL?

I thought it would be something like:

```
UPDATE tbl_Rem 
INNER JOIN qry_Values ON tbl_Rem.Rem_ID = qry_Values.Rem_ID 
SET tbl_Rem.Value = qry_Values.Value
```

But this is updating too many records in `tbl_Rem`

**edit**

I've been an idiot: the query wasn't running as I expected and was returning extra `Rem_ID`s that I hadn't picked up on!

Comment: Are you trying to update on a specific value?

Comment: I'm trying to update all the values in tbl_Rem where the Rem_ID exists in the query

Comment: Well what do you mean by too many records? Is it updating records where the Rem_ID doesn't exist?

Comment: Please don't delete - someone could learn from your mistake. I recommend cleaning up your question a bit, and then answering your own question with what the problem did and what your solution was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my **edit** in the question, the issue was not with my `update` query, but rather with my `qry_Values` as it was returning too many records as I had missed a `join`.

I spotted the error by rebuilding `qry_Values` from scratch, and this highlighted what I was missing.